# Laravel .env Error 775 application installer not going ahead?

Tags: laravel

My larevel app insatller is not going ahead with this error seen in picture below i am using windows 10 with Xampp

[image]

Tried .env permission

[image]

Comment: what command did you entered?

Comment: what do you mean its's default installer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a permission issue try to `set 644` for .env file which is standard for files.
You can do that by right-clicking on the file in windows & select properties.

Comment: edited the question as you can see permission in my list

Comment: Ok, now go to edit for authenticated users & tick off the full control.

Comment: what permission is the installer showing for .env now?

Comment: special permission off for all and 1. only full control off for authenticated users. 2. all ticks on for system & administrators. 3. only read & execute, read on for users. Then verify the permission changes for .env in installer & I hope it will work. (What I stated above is the default .env permission for laravel.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a permission problem.. as you dont have the right permission
Follow this link ! 
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/how-to-set-up-file-permissions-for-laravel`
hope It will Help You!

Comment: i am new to this and these sudo commands don't work with windows or i don't know where to  use these commands please guide

Answer (score 0):

Guys it wasn't working normally so i went on shared hosting and there were linux permisssions and i modified them and it worked and i cloned the REPO to my local server and solved the issue tahnks for the feedback